# D&D book where water could be boiled into gunpowder

Tags: story-identification, books, dungeons-and-dragons

I've been trying to find a book series I read when I was a kid. I don't have much information but one of the main things I remember was they invented gunpowder by using magic to boil water into a powder, and was ignited by rehydrating it. This was a major plot point several times.

I also remember that the cleric lost their holiness but don't remember how. Also every time someone cast a spell the text read something like "words that can only be heard and forgotten".

Comment: Can you remember anything about the overall plot? As we don't know when you was a kid, could you give a year range? Would it have been new at the time? Can you remember how many books would have been in this run? Did you read more than this one? You call out the gunpowder being a major plot point a few times, can you remember how? If you have the answers to any of these questions or want to add anything else you may remember about the book please [edit] those details into the question itself!

Comment: I've marked this one as a Duplicate because we've had it before, but please understand that this is not a censure. You have a good question. This is just some bookkeeping that we do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is *[Guardians of the Flame](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/GuardiansOfTheFlame)* (TV Tropes link) by Joel Rosenberg.

> **Guardians of the Flame** is a fantasy series by Joel Rosenberg about a group of roleplaying college students who abruptly find themselves inside the world of their game, in the bodies of their characters. The first book, The Sleeping Dragon, depicts their attempt to return to Earth, and their later commitment to return. Theater student/huge fighter Karl Cullinane vows to end slavery in his new home and persuades his friends to join the crusade. The remainder of the series follows his efforts, and later those of his son Jason.

The game that they play is not D&D, but is similar enough that a lot of the tropes carry over. Karl and Lou use their scientific knowledge to recreate actual gunpowder to give them an edge against the slavers. The slavers, in turn, create their own explosive power by boiling water inside of a sphere made indestructible via magic, and capturing that explosive power in a blue powder that ignites when it's made wet.

Doria is the cleric who lost her faith. Initially, she can't pray to regain her spells because she doesn't believe in a benevolent god due to her experiences on our Earth.

> "I tried. Honest, I tried. But it just didn't work."
>
> He didn't bother to keep the anger, the frustration out of his voice. "You tried what?"
>
> "Praying. To the Healing Hand. But nothing happened." She scratched at the back of her hand, leaving long red weals. "I can feel the other spells in my head. All of them, but I can't get the one I used back." A stray blond strand came to rest over one eye; she pushed it away. "Maybe..."
>
> "Maybe what?" This was frightening; the one thing he had been able to count on was their magic working.
>
> "Maybe if I believed..."
>
> He grabbed her shoulders and shook her. "You mean to tell me that with all that's happened to us, you don't believe in magic?"
>
> "Stop it. Stop it." He let her shrug his hands away. "It's not that. It's just that the notion of a god of the Healing Hand, a..."
>
> "Benign deity?"
>
> "Doing good, healing people, it just seems so absurd." She fastened slim fingers in her hair. "After all that's happened to us, after all that's happened to me, I just can't accept that. Not really."

And the world they travel to does use [Vancian Magic](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/VancianMagic), which describes held spells as words buzzing around in one's head, and the words not being able to be remembered clearly.

> Strange, liquid syllables issued from her barely parted lips, starting slowly, then becoming a torrent. Ahira could hear the words distinctly, tried to memorize them.
>
> But he couldn't. Not a phrase, not a word, not a syllable. They vanished from his mind like a snowflake melting on a palm.

Quotes pulled from [the free online copy of the first book](https://www.baen.com/Chapters/0743435893/0743435893.htm) courtesy of the publisher, Baen.

Comment: Yes that Guardians of the flame was the book series you are awesome. I couldn't remember if it was approved by wizards of the coast or not to make it an actual d&d book ya know legality and what not.